# Copying file locally from one location to another and checking if file exists

Tags: java

I have the code which copies the .zip files from one location to another. It works as expected. 
I want to check if the copied file exists in the folder. If it does it should continue else copy the file.

I believe my logic is correct but I am not sure where I am going wrong because it does not check if file exists or not

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

public class ZipFileMover
{

  public void findFiles(File root, int depth)
      throws IOException
  {
    File[] listOfFiles = root.listFiles();
    for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++)
    {
      String iName = listOfFiles[i].getName();
      if (listOfFiles[i].isFile())
      {
        if (iName.endsWith(".zip"))
        {
          for (int j = 0; j < depth; j++)
          {}
          System.out.println("Files: " + iName);
          File dest = new File(
              "C:\\Users\\somename\\Documents\\Development\\ZipFiles\\"
                  + iName);

          String path = "C:\\Users\\somename\\Documents\\Development\\ZipFiles\\"
              + iName;

          // C:\Users\somename\Documents\Development\

          // System.out.println("ROOT + iNAME : " + (root + "\\" + iName));
          // //C:\Users\somename\Documents\Development\filename.zip

          boolean check = new File(dest, iName).exists();
          System.out.println(check);

          if ((root + "\\" + iName).equals(path))
          {
            continue;
          }
          else
          {
            if (check == true)
            {
              System.out.println(
                  "Skipped file " + iName + " it already exsits in folder.");
              continue;

            }
            else
            {
              System.out.println();
              System.out.println("Copying file " + iName);
              System.out.println();
              FileUtils.copyFile(new File(root + "\\" + iName), dest);
            }

          }
        }
      }
      else if (listOfFiles[i].isDirectory())
      {
        for (int j = 0; j < depth; j++)
          findFiles(listOfFiles[i], depth + 1);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: why in your second for loop using j as your increment, do you have nothing in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
boolean check = dest.exists();
```

Comment: I want to check if the `iName` exists in `dest`.. Plus `File` requires 2 parameters. It wont work with just one.

Comment: File just stores the path and exists method check for this file in this path exists. Test it. You can also use: `boolean check = new File("C:\\Users\\somename\\Documents\\Development\\ZipFiles\‌​\", iName).exists();`. I changed my answer to be cleaner

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you use the debug feature of your IDE, It will help you determine where your logical errors lie.

Side note: don't add more if's and else's than you absolutely have to it makes the code difficult to follow, This should simplify it.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

public class ZipFileMover
{
  static String outputPath = "C:\\Users\\somename\\Documents\\Development\\ZipFiles\\";

  public void findFiles(File root, int depth)
      throws IOException
  {
    File[] listOfFiles = root.listFiles();
    for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++)
    {
      String iName = listOfFiles[i].getName();
      if (listOfFiles[i].isFile() && iName.endsWith(".zip"))
      {
        System.out.println("Files: " + iName);
        File dest = new File(outputPath + iName);
        if (dest.exists())
        {
          System.out.println(
              "Skipped file " + iName + " it already exsits in folder.");
          continue;
        }
        else if ((root + "\\" + iName).equals(dest))
        {
          continue;
        }
        else
        {
          System.out.println();
          System.out.println("Copying file " + iName);
          System.out.println();
          FileUtils.copyFile(listOfFiles[i], dest);
        }
      }
      else if (listOfFiles[i].isDirectory())
      {
        for (int j = 0; j < depth; j++)
          findFiles(listOfFiles[i], depth + 1);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip but when I run your code, it returns me with `java.io.IOException: Destination 'C:\Users\somename\Documents\Development\ZipFiles' directory cannot be created` error. I am not sure why it would do that. Any insight to that will be helpful.

Comment: The stack trace would be more helpful, are you sure you can make a new user folder called `somename`? Start by simplifying your output to go to an existing directory that you know you have permissions to.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to update my comment. I figured that thing out n YES i had forgot to change the somename to the name required.

Comment: Glad to be of service, please consider accepting my answer if you found it most helpful, and have a good day. Also make sure you saw my edit to the copy files line, as you should not be creating another file when you already have a reference to the source file you want to copy.